Customize title bar and solve window dragging in winform blazor hybrid
I use blazor hybrid development mode in winform. The problem now is to use web components instead of native title bar. I achieve the form of moving winform by dragging the titlebar in the following way, but it can be felt that it is not as smooth as the native control dragging, and there is a little lag. Is there any better way to solve this problem? I did not find this phenomenon in similar electron applications
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark" @onmousedown="MouseDown">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Avalonia Blazor Hybrid</a>
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
@code{
    public void MouseDown(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        _isMoving = true;
        var startPosition = Control.MousePosition;

        _startWindLeft = startPosition.X - Program.MainWindow.Location.X;
        _startWindTop = startPosition.Y - Program.MainWindow.Location.Y;

        DragWindow();
    }

    public void DragWindow()
    {
        var mainWindow = Program.MainWindow;

        while (_isMoving)
        {
            if (Control.MouseButtons != MouseButtons.Left || Form.ActiveForm != mainWindow)
            {
                _isMoving = false;
                break;
            }
            var cursor = Control.MousePosition;
            mainWindow.Location = new((int)(cursor.X - _startWindLeft), (int)(cursor.Y - _startWindTop));
        };
    }
}


You can refer to this case: How to drag and drop the Blazor component.

@JianweiSun-MSFT ,What I want to achieve is to move the winform form by dragging the custom title bar. Maybe my description is not clear enough, so I have added the description. I see that the example you gave seems to be dragging the web component. Can this meet this requirement?

@JianweiSun-MSFT Thank you for your reply. I achieved this goal by calling win32api through the related answer and got a good experience.

I achieved this by:
<div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark" @onpointerdown="MouseDown" >

@code{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
    const uint MOUSE_MOVE = 0xF012;      

    public void DragMe()
    {
        DefWindowProc(Program.MainWindow.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (UIntPtr)MOUSE_MOVE, IntPtr.Zero);
    }


    private void MouseDown()
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        this.DragMe(); 
    }
}

